# All networking broken after running Remote-SSH on VSCode

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, netplan

I'm really stumped here and so are my friends. I've tried every fix in the book and thus far nothing has worked. I wanted to try out VSCode's Remote-SSH feature so I installed VSCode and the Remote Development extension on my VPS and my local machine. Everything was great, I opened `/root/` and started messing around in the terminal. Here's the weird part, when I tried opening a file, `dead.letter` if you were wondering, my VPS just died. It basically obliterated all networking functions and instantly dropped my SSH connection. My web server died, everything just died. All inbound and outbound connections just died. It also entirely deleted netplan and the `/etc/netplan` directory. I've remade the netplan config, I've re-symlinked `/etc/resolv.conf`, I've reinstalled netplan by mounting an ISO with the DEB file, I've restarted so many networking services. Help would be greatly appreciated because the web server runs a forum and the users are a bit sad.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is really bizarre.  I am tempted to wonder if your system was malware infected or something.  Anyway, how are your backups?  Might be easiest to just rebuild the VPS from your backups?

Comment: @Zoredache The sad thing is I can't get the backups off the system because it has no networking. The only way I'm able to access it is direct over KVM, thank goodness my host gave us that.

Comment: You must not use `root` account for daily activities. Always use a normal user account to have protection against events like this.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I see that now :(

Comment: VPS providers often have rescue systems, which can be used to restore backups.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yep, I used Rescue Mode, and I didn't really have any backups come to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to mark my own question as resolved because after hours of fiddling with system hostname files and iptables it now works again...still not sure what happened.

Comment: do you have any more info on what you did to solve this? Since trying vscode remote from OSX to Raspberry Pi, I can no longer connect to the pi from this mac.  All other devices are fine, and I can do an ssh hop to get onto it, but I can't even ping directly between the Pi and the mac anymore.

Comment: @JamesP not really, me and my hosting provider just messed around with iptables until everything worked